# How difficult is to migrate from Windows to Linux without any experience with Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, windows, migration, mariadb

I have an immense background with Microsoft Windows Server (from Windows NT to the latest server editions), but now I am forced to move some services off Windows Server platform to reduce hosting costs.

Within the next couple of months, I will have to deploy the following bundle:

- Apache (httpd)
- MariaDB
- MongoDB Community Server
- Secure FTP server

to a one of these:

- Debian
- Ubuntu
- CentOS

My experience with Linux is non-existent. Therefore *I am genuinely concerned* with how I'm going to be able to do my job, deploying and maintaining the above-mentioned software on Lunix.

Here comes my question:

> assuming I learn fast and have a deep understanding of general principles of how the services, **how difficult will be to migrate the bundle to Linux?**

Saying *migrate* I mean that I will have to roll out the bits at least for the development environment.

What of the above distributions is preferrable in terms of manageability and security? Will I have to manage the server from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to hire someone who knows what s/he is doing and work/learn with them.

Tacking on such a job without any prior Linux knowledge is a recipe for disaster.

If your company / your boss will not give you time to learn and experiment and at the same time will not hire someone experienced and just dump everything on you, then it's time to look for a new job.